# Why didn't Lucius recognize Harry in the Malfoy Manor?

Tags: harry-potter

We know that Lucius has seen Harry several times and that he knows he is most of the times with Hermione and Ron.

I'm re-watching *Harry Potter* and in the movie, Hermione disfigures Harry but not enough and the Snatchers are not sure if he is himself and from what I remember from the book, the Snatchers identified Hermione who was known to be with Harry and therefore brought them to the Malfoy Manor. In any case they believe it could be Harry, why wasn't Lucius sure if he was Harry? Maybe Draco didn't want to identify Harry for any reason but I'm sure that Lucius would have.

Comment: ummm, *Harry's disfigured face* ? The movies, as usual, didn't do the job well in disfiguring Harry as the books mentioned.

Comment: Because who has time to learn what kids look like?

Comment: @Valorum -- Well, when you've got the Dark Lord's wand up your ass and when the one thing in all the world said Dark Lord wants is Harry Potter, one would think Mr Malfoy would know what Harry looks like. If for no other reason than to extricate himself from the said wand.

Comment: @Valorum They're kinda arch enimies, so you'd think they know what each other look like...

Comment: @Valorum Not to mention he has met Harry like 5 times at least and fairly recently during Half Blood Prince too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the books, after Harry, in his excitement says the Dark Lord's name out loud, the Snatchers start to apparate outside their tent and all their defensive spells are disabled.

As soon as Hermione realizes that they have been caught, she uses the Stinging hex on Harry which disfigures his face. Back at the Malfoy Manor, Lucius is informed by Narcissa and the Snatchers that they believe that the individual with the disfigured face is Harry Potter.

Malfoy is also convinced (to a certain extent) that it is Harry, but he isn't so sure, so he asks his son - Draco - if he recognises him. Unfortunately, Malfoy isn't sure of it as well, so Lucius has no evidence or confirmation that it is Harry.

Additionally, he did not want to call the Dark Lord as a false alarm could have dire consequences for him.

Comment: I will add quotes from the book as soon as I can.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the books that Draco recognizes Harry/Hermione/Ron. But *fortunately*, he's too afraid of the consequences so he pretends he doesn't recognize them.

Comment: The last line is the key detail here. Voldemort is a bad boss, so his underlings are ineffective at doing his bidding.

Comment: @Kevin So he still failed to listen to you? https://imgur.com/gallery/VFiOZ